# Choosing items only once subject to slot constraints

Tags: python, or-tools

I have a set of many (10000+) items, from which have I have to choose exactly `k` items. I can only choose each item once.

Each item is represented as a tuple:

`item = ('item code', cost, profit, slot_1, slot_2, ...., slot_N)`
as an example

`vase = ['000001', 1000, 10000, 1, 0, ..., 0]`

`plate = ['000002', 10, 5, 0, 1, ..., 0]`

and the total set of items is a list of lists:

`items = [item1, item2, ..., itemN]`

My profits and costs are also lists:

`profits = [x[2] for x in items]`

`costs = [x[1] for x in items]`

I represent if an item can be in slot_j as a list of lists:

```
slots = []

for j in NUM_SLOTS:
    slot[j, :] = [x[3+j] for x in items]
```

My problem is that items with the same code can appear in multiple slots, but can only be chosen once irrespective of the slot.

ie. `vase = ['000001', 1000, 10000, 1, 0, ..., 1]`

I'm confused about how I add the constraint that an item can only be chosen once if it is available in multiple slots.

Only one item can be chosen per slot.

The entire program is below for reference.

```
from ortools.linear_solver import pywraplp

solver = pywraplp.Solver('SolveAssignmentProblemMIP',

pywraplp.Solver.CBC_MIXED_INTEGER_PROGRAMMING)

x = {}

for i in range(MAX_ITEMS):
    x[i] = solver.BoolVar('x[%s]' % (i))

#Define the constraints 
total_chosen = 100
solver.Add(solver.Sum([x[i] for i in range(MAX_ITEMS)]) == 
total_chosen)

max_cost = 5.0

for i in range(num_recipes):
    solver.Add(x[i] * cost[i] <= max_cost)

### Only choose one item per slot
for i in range(1, num_slots):
    slot = slots[:, i]
    solver.Add(solver.Sum([x[j] * slot[j] for j in range(MAX_ITEMS)]) == 1)

solver.Maximize(solver.Sum([profits[i] * x[i] for i in 
range(total_chosen)]))
sol = solver.Solve()
```

Comment: This sounds like [Multi-Dimensional Knapsack Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Multi-dimensional_knapsack_problem), where the cost is your first dimension (if cost is bounded at all, which is not entirely clear), and each slot is another dimension with maximum capacity 1 and each item having 0 or 1 weight in that dimension.

Comment: On closer inspection, the question does not even state whether or not more than one item can be chosen per slot. I found this somewhat self-evident, and maybe you forgot to explicitly mention this for this reason, but can you clarify, please?

Comment: Only one item can be chosen per slot

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding a dummy for each unique code:

```
valid = pd.DataFrame(data=[x for x in l ], columns=['code', 'slot', 'cost', 'score'])

code_dummies = pd.get_dummies(valid['code'].unique())

valid = pd.concat([valid, code_dummies], axis=1)
```

And then adding the following constraint:

```
codes = valid['code'].unique()
for i in range(len(codes)):
    code = valid[codes[i]]
    solver.Add(solver.Sum([x[j] * code[j] for j in range(num_recipes)]) <= 1)
```